# JS + Vue3: Modal dialog: call parameterized function returned by function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

First of all, I am not sure whether this is a Vue thing or just a JavaScript related question.
I wrote some code which finally works, but I don't know why. Maybe you can enlighten me.

I created a "dialog window" component. It is a simple (modal) dialog which takes a function as a parameter. If the user clicks OK the function is called - like "Do you really want to delete that file?" Cancel or OK.

The function I pass to the component has sometimes a parameter itself.
So I want to pass the already **parameterized function** as a parameter to my component.
I achieve this by wrapping the function in an arrow function which **returns** the parameterized function which then can be called.

The idea of this concept in pure JS looks like this:

```js
//the function to be finally executed
function say(message) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = message;
}

//the parameterized function inside of an arrow function (as a variable)
const sayhelloworld = () => say("hello world");

//finally I call the arrow function which 
//returns the parameterized function and calls this one as well
function start() {
  sayhelloworld()(); //this is the core of my question: the double brackets!
}
```

So I need double brackets. The first () returns the function inside and the second () calls it.
And it does work exactly like this:
https://codepen.io/keztur/pen/powaLJN

Now let's turn to vue:

I open my dialog component with an event bus (sorry about that) and pass a parameter object including the function parameter.
(I use Vue 3 - so behind my EventBus object is actually the 'mitt' library: https://github.com/developit/mitt)

```
//component calling the dialog and passing the function parameter 
//(as a part of a parameter object)
EventBus.emit("OpenDialog", {
    header: "Delete file",
    body: "Do you really want to delete that file?",
    function: () => this.Delete(file_id)
});
```

Modal-component:

```
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
      ModalProps: {
        header: "",
        body: "",
        function: ""
      }
    };
  },

//inside of the modal component this function is called 
//if the user clicks any of the two buttons (cancel or OK)
  methods: {
    clicked(button) {
      if (button === 'ok' && typeof this.ModalProps.function === 'function') {
        this.ModalProps.function(); //why does this work ...
       //this.ModalProps.function()(); //...but not this?
 //the second line does call the function but also throws an error afterwards
      }
      this.show = false; //modal is closed
    }
  },
... etc.
```

So at first I was using the double brackets as in my JS example above. And the function was called properly but the second "execution" backets obviously threw an error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler 
  at <Modal> 
  at <App>
```

But since I deleted the second bracket, everything works just fine.

So my question is: Why is in Vue the function inside my arrow function called right away and not just returned by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example doesn't work. It only should be `sayhelloworld();`. Open the (browser or codepen) console when running it. It will say:

> ```
> TypeError: sayhelloworld() is not a function
> ```

It only looks like it's working, because there is no more to do after the error. Try adding, for example, `alert("Done")` after `sayhelloworld()();` and you'll notice that the alert is never shown.

The difference in Vue is that Vue catches and displays the error.

`sayhelloworld` (and `this.ModalProps.function`in your Vue example) are just normal (references to) functions, which don't return anything. There is no(*) difference between

```
const sayhelloworld = () => say("hello world");
```

and

```
const sayhelloworld = function() {
  say("hello world");
}
```

and

```
function sayhelloworld() {
  say("hello world");
}
```

You would use `()()` if the function returns a function itself, for example:

```
function sayhelloworld() {
  const innerFunction = function () {
    say("hello world");
  }
  return innerFunction;
}
```

or

```
function sayhelloworld() {
  return () => say("hello world");
}
```

or even

```
const sayhelloworld = () => () => say("hello world");
```

Again these examples do the same thing(*).

---

(*) They are not completely identical, mostly regarding [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) and how the handling of `this` inside the function, but that isn't relevant here.

Comment: Thank you very much! I already assumed that the issue had something to do with js (and my limited knowledge in that field). But I could have sworn I tried to run the codepen example with just one bracket... sigh

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a universal component, [@unoverlays/vue](https://unoverlays.vercel.app/en/vue/) can help you

```html
<!-- overlay.vue -->
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue'
import { useOverlayMeta } from '@unoverlays/vue'
const props = defineProps({
  content: String,
})
// Get overlay information from useOverlayMeta
const { visible, resolve, reject } = useOverlayMeta({
  // Duration of the overlay animation to avoid premature component destruction
  animation: 1000,
})
</script>

<template>
  <!-- Customized modal using vuetify -->
  <v-dialog v-model="visible">
    <div>{{ content }}</div>

    <button @click="resolve(`${content}:confirmed`)"> click confirm </button>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

You can use the `defineOverlay/renderOverlay` method to convert the component into a modal dialog in Javascript / Typescript, which allows you to call it.

```
import { defineOverlay } from '@unoverlays/vue'
import OverlayComponent from './overlay.vue'

// Convert to imperative callback
const callback = defineOverlay(OverlayComponent)
// Call the component and get the value of the resolve callback
const value = await callback({ content: 'callbackOverlay' })
// value === "callbackOverlay:confirmed"
```

Additionally, it supports context inheritance